# How Can We Remove Slash '/' which is at end of $file_info[path]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am fetching Folder Path with the help of values stored in database, I am getting exact path name with `$file_info[path]` but this is getting output with `/` at end of every folder.

This above code is showing path like :

```
/folders/New Files/Latest/
```

And I want result like

```
/folders/New Files/Latest
```

Guys Please tell me exact solution for this query.

Comment: can you please tell how to use substr() exactly ?

Comment: @KailashGhodke, yes. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to correct your variable so it doesn't append the last `/`.

In the meantime though I'd use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
echo rtrim('/folders/New Files/Latest/', '/');
```

Output:

```
/folders/New Files/Latest
```

Demo: https://eval.in/463160

This way you can be sure you are only removing a `/`s from the end of the string. (Note if `///` were the ending and you only want one to be removed this wouldn't do that, this will remove all trailing `/`s).

Comment: Thank you so much @chris85 ! With echo it showing perfect result; but when I tried it with my code It's not working...

Comment: `$folder = "rtrim(''.$file_info[path].'', '/')" ` here is what I trying

Comment: Take off the quotes. `$folder = rtrim($file_info['path'], '/');`. Also `path` should be in quotes if it is a string.

Comment: I tried as per you said but still not working on my code , I am adding code here please check out `$folder = rtrim($file_info['path'], '/'); $down = "$folder/$to";` this is what I need in my old script it was like `$folder = "/folder"; $down = "$folder/$to";` Then It works perfect ! CAn you please tell me where I am doing mistakes ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Is this an accurate example of what you are encountering? https://eval.in/463194

Comment: @KailashGhodke figured it out?

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the last position of a / in the path:

```
if (strrpos($path, '/')==strlen($path)-1){
    // remove last character
    $path = substr($path,0,strlen($path)-1);
}
```

Comment: *If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string*. You do not need to call `strlen()`, can just set length to `-1` to remove last character.

Comment: Thanks for this optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()` for this.

`substr($file_info[path], 0, -1);`

If the value is '/folders/New Files/Latest/', it will now be '/folders/New Files/Latest'.